# Having issues joining my kubernetes worker noed to a controller node

Tags: docker, containers, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, ubuntu-16.04

"error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get "https://master-node.xxxxx.xxxxx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)".

The above error kept showing anytime I tried to connect my worker to my master node in a kubernetes cluster.

I tried to add my worker node to the controller node but ended up with the error.
It is supposed to be succesful, but it kept throwing the error even after disabling my firewall and ensured that the kube api server is up and running. Also, I ensured that the dns resolution on master-node.xxxxx.xxxxx, and it is working just fine.
But the aforementioned error keeps popping up anytime I tried to establish a join connection from the worker to the master

Comment: The error you're describing could originate from a number of networking issues. What could help analyze this is specifying the command you used to bootstrap the worker node. Are you using `kubeadm`? What is your master node `--apiserver-advertise-address` ? Is port '6443' on the master node open?

Comment: Like I said, the firewall has been disabled, hence port opening isn't valid anymore.
kubeadm is what I used for initializing my cluster from the control plane.
Both the worker nodes and the master node are sitting on a private subnet, and they could ping each other, even with the registered hostnames.